# How to configure a self-chosen switch in wsl?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyper-v

Is there a way to change "wsl 2" use of network switches. I have existing virtual machines that run on bridged (basically get assigned their own ip address from the dhcp, on the router), so because of an existing switch, hyper-v doesn't allow me to reassign the wsl switch the same adapter.

Basically, wsl seems to create/destroy their "wsl" adapter, and automatically assign an internal ip address with different subnets. This is causing me some issues with playing around with mDNS broadcasts, because incoming traffic can't directly interact with my lan.

I wouldn't mind reassigning something occasionally, but the fact that wsl is deleting and destroying switches on demand, basically causes me to continuously break my virtual machines. Ideally I'm looking for a way I could  just configure wsl to always just use the switch I'm using for my existing vm's.

Is something like this possible?